# Include file within variable

Tags: php, variables, include

Thank you all for your help ; I found many responses to my questions on this forum but still stuck on this one . Let me explain:
I have files called “participant_pledge.php” , “parents_pledge.php” …. That contain text only. The reason for it is that this text is needed in many files within my website; so I simply use “include” wherever I need it. 
My problem is that I also need to include those file in the content of some “email function.”
That’s where I can’t find solution to include those file since it isn’t possible to use a function within a variable. The idea would be to be able to do the following:

```
function update ($user_id, $update_camper_data) {
...
$message='
 ...
<tr>
<td>
Participant\'s Name*:
</td>
<td>
'.$update_camper_data['participant_first_name'].'  '.$update_camper_data['participant_middle_initial'].'  '.$update_camper_data['participant_last_name'].'
</td>

include ‘participant_pledge.php;  //which does not work inside a variable

...';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

I have considered constant variables but could not make it work (but maybe I used it the wrong way)…
Anyways, thank you in advance for your time and help on this question.

Mike.

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact possible in a way to use a 'function within a variable'.  See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php.  The pattern you are describing is basically that ofa 'View Helper'.  Maybe look at some frameworks and how they implement this.  For example: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html

Comment: Another resource: http://www.rvdavid.net/template-view-and-view-helper-design-patterns-in-php/

Comment: I am  little confused by your post. I am not sure how to use anonymous function in that context or the zend framework. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should look into storing the text in a database. That way, all you'll need to do is query the database, instead of including the "text only" PHP files.

Comment: I would like to avoid doing that if possible... it is not very practicle to go into the database everytime I need to change text... moreover the file is not only text; there is some variables such as that are called. Thanks a lot.